# Regex: How can I change the order of the lines after dot?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

How can I change the order of the lines after dot with regex?

> Numai într-un context dăunător personal sau social poate fi descrisă transferul ca o problemă patologică. O perspectivă modernă, social-cognitivă a transferului explică modul în care aceasta poate apărea în viața de zi cu zi. Când oamenii întâlnesc o persoană nouă care le amintește de altcineva. Ei deduc în mod inconștient că noua persoană are trăsături similare cu persoana cunoscută anterior [5]. Această perspectivă a generat o multitudine de cercetări care au luminat modul în care oamenii tind să repete tipare de relații din trecut în prezent.

should be transform in something like this:

> Ei deduc în mod inconștient că noua persoană are trăsături similare cu persoana cunoscută anterior [5]. Această perspectivă a generat o multitudine de cercetări care au luminat modul în care oamenii tind să repete tipare de relații din trecut în prezent. Când oamenii întâlnesc o persoană nouă care le amintește de altcineva. Numai într-un context dăunător personal sau social poate fi descrisă transferul ca o problemă patologică. O perspectivă modernă, social-cognitivă a transferului explică modul în care aceasta poate apărea în viața de zi cu zi.

I myself consider this, but it not very good:

Search: `(?-s)^(.+?\.)(\w+)((?1))`

Replace by: `\4\2\1\3`

Comment: Why is it not very good? What's the issue?

Comment: because is not working :) see this print screen  https://snag.gy/QpEnfs.jpg

Comment: Of course it doesn't match, what's the purpose of `\w+`? There're no word characters after a dot in this text.

Comment: If I understandyou have 5 sentences and you want the new order to be `4 5 3 1 2` , am I right? Do you want to change this specific text only or are there some other texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reorder sentences (any number of them) but not really random.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)(.+?\.)\h*((?1))(?:\h*((?1)))?`
- Replace with: `$2(?3 $3 : )$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
  ^             # beginning of line
 |              # OR
  \G            # restart from last match position
)               # end group
(.+?\.)         # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy, followed by a dot
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
((?1))          # group 2, same pattern as group 1
(?:             # non capture group
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  ((?1))        # group 3, same pattern as group 1
)?              #end group, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2              # content of group 2
(?3 $3 : )      # if group 3 exists then content of group 3, else a space
$1              # content of group 3
```

**Result for given example:**

> O perspectivă modernă, social-cognitivă a transferului explică modul în care aceasta poate apărea în viața de zi cu zi. Când oamenii întâlnesc o persoană nouă care le amintește de altcineva. Numai într-un context dăunător personal sau social poate fi descrisă transferul ca o problemă patologică.Această perspectivă a generat o multitudine de cercetări care au luminat modul în care oamenii tind să repete tipare de relații din trecut în prezent.  Ei deduc în mod inconștient că noua persoană are trăsături similare cu persoana cunoscută anterior [5].

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: hello Toto, I need an entire text to reorder lines. Something like 400 sentences. :)

Comment: @JustMe: OK, but what are the rules to define the order?

Comment: none. randomly. the order of all sentences must be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Perl one-liner that works with any number of sentences and print all sentences in random order.

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN{use List::Util qw/shuffle/;$/="."}chomp;s/^\h*//;push @l,$_ if length$_>2;END{say join(". ",shuffle@l),"."}' file.txt
```

**Output:**

> O perspectivă modernă, social-cognitivă a transferului explică modul în care aceasta poate apărea în viața de zi cu zi. Când oamenii întâlnesc o persoană nouă care le amintește de altcineva. Ei deduc în mod inconștient că noua persoană are trăsături similare cu persoana cunoscută anterior [5]. Numai într-un context dăunător personal sau social poate fi descrisă transferul ca o problemă patologică. Această perspectivă a generat o multitudine de cercetări care au luminat modul în care oamenii tind să repete tipare de relații din trecut în prezent.

**Explanation:**

```
perl -nE                        # invoke perl interpreter
'                               # begin code
  BEGIN{                        # block executed before anything
    use List::Util qw/shuffle/; # use a module
    $/="."                      # define input separator as a dot
  }                             # end block
  chomp;                        # remove separator
  s/^\h*//;                     # remove horizontal whitespace at the beginning or a sentence
  push @l,$_ if length$_>2;     # push the sentence in an array if its length is greater than 2
  END{                          # block executed  at the end of the program
    say join(". ",shuffle@l),"." # prints randomly each sentence
  }                             # end block
'                               # end code
file.txt                        # file to be processed
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know Perl, just how to use Regex on notepad++  :(

Comment: @JustMe: You cannot do such thing (undefined number of sentences) with regex.

Comment: @JustMe: Have a try with: Find: `(?:^|\G)(.+?\.)\h*((?1))\h*((?1))` Replace: `$2(?3 $3 : )$1` "Replace all". What do you think about this?

Comment: great. So, you see, Toto. It can be done ! Please make from your last reply an ANSWER, so I can vote !!

Comment: @JustMe: Done, but be aware this is not really random.

Comment: Toto, I find another good explanation here. Take a look, just to see a different approach  https://bit.ly/31lhNpw